# Issue launching project with VisualVM eclipse plugin

Tags: java, swing, visualvm, jvisualvm

An internal error occurred during: "Launching ModificationToolkit".

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaLaunchDelegate.launch(JavaLaunchDelegate.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.visualvm.launcher.java.VisualVMJavaDelegate.launch(VisualVMJavaDelegate.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I've seen this on the Internet a bit, but there doesn't seem to be a resolution for it. My project launches fine without using this plugin, and this issue **also** affects my other projects (if I attempt to launch using VisualVM).

Using this version of VisualVM - http://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html

Comment: any luck at getting this one fixed? I'm having the same issue with STS 3.4.0

Comment: I registered and filed a support request, they acknowledged the issue but I haven't had time to check if they fixed it.

Comment: check the Java version being used. you may get the problem whe you are adding a new JRE (Window->Preferences->Installed JREs, same location as the not working one), making it the default and deleting the old (misbehaving one). With the new (from the same location) JRE starting Java applications in debug will work fine.

Comment: Already tried that Kathir, but thankyou :)

Comment: Any luck getting this resolved? I tried removing and re-installing the plugin but it didn't help...

Comment: None as of yet, sadly. If I find something, I'll update this question with an answer. Reverted to using JVisualVM at this point (with the annoyances of starting that up from command line).

Answer (score 18):

As I first installed it, (as told on the page you gave me,) it did work.
So I need some information first:

- What eclipse version do you use?
- What paths did you set?
- What JDK version(s) do you have installed.
- What VisualVM versions do they have.
- If any seperate installed, what JRE versions do you have?

*How to get the paths of your VisualVM plugin:*

1. Inside eclipse: open the **GLOBAL** Preferences (Window>Preferences)
2. In your **GLOBAL** Preferences: "Run/Debug">"Launching">"VisualVM Configuration"
3. There should be to paths. The first one is the path to the VisualVM Executable. The second one is your JDK home. (the jdk-home path should match the VisualVM's jdk-home path)

*How to get the version of VisualVM:*

1. Navigate to your JDK folder.
2. Inside the 'bin' folder there should be a executable (with a fancy icon) called 'visualvm' with any extension. (I don't know what os you are using and its irrelevant)
3. Start it...
4. On the menubar: Help>About. On the dialog look at the lower left corner. (Mostly it matches your JDK version)

Comment: In my case, there was nothing in the VisualVM Executable and the JDK home pointed to a JRE. I changed both and now it works. One important thing is that if the application runs using a 32 bit JRE (or JDK), the JDK of VisualVM must be 32 bit as well.